# nhibernate save() generated insert statement but no actual record was inserted into db

Tags: database, nhibernate, session, insert, save

I have the following code. In SQL Server profiler I can see the insert statement being generated however no actual record has been inserted. I just can't figure out why this is happening!

```
private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
private Configuration _configuration;

_configuration = new Configuration();
_configuration.Configure();
_configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Task).Assembly);
_sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

using (var s = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var t = s.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
{
    var taskToSave = new Task
                         {
                             Class = "test class",
                             IsActive = true,
                             Namespace = "test namespace"
                         };

    s.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
    s.Save(taskToSave);
    t.Commit();
}
```

My mapping file is like this:

```
<class name="Task" table="Task">
  <id name="Id" column="Id" unsaved-value="0" type="Int32">
    <generator class ="identity"></generator>
  </id>

  <property name="IsActive" column="IsActive" not-null="true" type="Boolean" />
  <property name="Namespace" column="Namespace" length="255" not-null="true" type="String" />
  <property name="Class" column="Class" length="255" not-null="true" type="String" />
</class>
```

Thank you! BTW I am using NHibernate-2.1.0.CR1.

Comment: It was because I had SchemaExport somewhere in the code without me realizing it and when the code runs SchemaExport created a new table called dbo_owner_Task and inserted into that table instaed of dbo.Task.

Comment: (Jeffrey, if that last comment you posted is the answer to your question, than you should post that as an Answer. Then mark it as the best Answer with the checkmark button.)

Comment: Mufasa, I did post it as an answer. However it must have been deleted by some one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I had `SchemaExport` somewhere in the code without me realizing it and when the code runs SchemaExport created a new table called `dbo_owner_Task` and inserted into that table instead of `dbo.Task`.

So becareful when using SchemaExport!